# Maximal minors of tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, determinants, tensor-products, integer-matrices

Let $r \leq n$ be integers, and let $A$ be an $r \times n$ integer-valued matrix such that each $r\times r$ minor of $A$ is in $\{0, 1,-1\}$. Is it true that each $r^2 \times r^2$ minor of $A\otimes A$ is in $\{0, 1,-1\}$?

Comment: A counterexample (essentially the first one I stumbled upon at random): $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. $3\times3$-minors of $A\otimes A$ are all $\pm4$.

Comment: Oops sorry - by some reason I thought that for a square matrix by maximal minors you mean those of size one less...

Comment: Maybe you still add that you mean $r\times r$-minors? I've seen texts where just "minors", without any adjective, for an $n\times n$-matrix, is assumed to mean $(n-1)\times(n-1)$-minors. I believe the question might be confusing because of that. It confused me, at any rate :D

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to you as well!